# JPQL Query for ElementCollection

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpql

Assuming I have the following Entities and relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable( name="ORDER", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID") )  
    private List<Order> orders;

}

@Embeddable
public class Order {

    private long price;

}
```

Now I want to get all customers who don't have any orders or their orders price are below $100. I tried to it in many ways but it always generate something like:
SELECT t0.ID FROM CUSTOMER t0, ORDERS t1 WHERE ((t1.PRICE > 100) AND (t0.COACH_ID = t1.ID))

The problem is that it return all customers who have orders above 100 but not the ones who didn't make any order yet. It is caused because of the t0.COACH_ID = t1.ID.

I am using eclipse link 2.5 and I tried all options but couldn't make it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN c.orders o
WHERE o.price < 100 
OR c.orders IS EMPTY
```

I believe `LEFT JOIN` will do an outer-join, so it should still include customers without orders.